Set value of a selectOneMenu in a dataTable row based on an outputText column value in the same row, without backing bean
EDIT: Requirements were revised so a conditional label on the noSelectOption item was sufficient (code below). No longer need a solution, but feel free to post any.
<f:selectItem itemLabel="#{idMatch.assignedTo != null ? 'IN REVIEW' : 'Select Action'}" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />

Original post:
The following is a dataTable that has a selectOneMenu dropdown in the last column of each row.
I need to have the dropdown in each row set to "IN REVIEW" if idMatch.assignedTo in the same row is not null:
<h:form id="idForm">
    <p:dataTable id="dt_idtable" widgetVar="idTable" value="#{serviceBean.idEntries}" var="idMatch" >
        <p:column headerText="IDNUM">
            <h:outputText id="id_idnum" value="#{idMatch.idnum}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="ASSIGNED TO">
            <h:outputText id="id_assignTo" value="#{idMatch.assignedTo}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column headerText="ACTION">
            <p:selectOneMenu value="#{idMatch.selectedAction}" id="actionSelect" widgetVar="actionList" 
                onchange="setValuesAndSubmit('#{idMatch.idnum}', this.value)">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select Action" itemValue="" noSelectionOption="true" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="ADD" itemValue="ADD" />
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="IN REVIEW" itemValue="IN REVIEW" />
            </p:selectOneMenu>
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>

The dropdown is not tied to a managed bean because... reasons. The selected value is just passed as a param to a js function.
I've found that PF('actionList').selectValue("IN REVIEW"); can be used to set the dropdown value, but can't figure out how to traverse the table to set each dropdown.
This is my non-working script, which I'm guessing isn't looking up the correct id_assignTo, among other things.
Any help is greatly appreciated.
function setActionInReview() {
    var actionSelect = document.querySelectorAll("#actionSelect"), i;
    for (i=0; i< actionSelect.length; ++i) {
        if (document.getElementById('idForm:id_assignTo').value != null) {
            PF('actionList').selectValue("IN REVIEW");
        }
    }
}


try document.getElementById('id_assignTo') idk what this syntax is: 'idForm:id_assignTo'
